# Storage Spaces 'offline due to critical write failures; add drives'

Tags: windows, windows-10, hard-drive, storage-spaces

I am getting an error in Windows 10 Storage Spaces and the Virtual Volume has been taken offline. The error is Error Offline due to critical write failures; add drives.

If i look at the Physical drives within Storage Space Manager - then i can see all Physical disks are Okay and approx 49% used space. Also if i query the disks for errors i cannot see any:

[image: Storage Spaces]

[image: Disk Health]

[image: Get-PhysicalDisk]

[image: Bad Block]

I am not sure what to do and if there is a way i can repair the virtual volume and bring online...any help appreciated.

Comment: I haven’t used Storage Spaces for a long time. Perhaps you could check the disks’ SMART status using GSmartControl, Crystal Disk Info or whatever? If possible, please provide this information for all disks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is now on the way to being fixed...

I identified a potential faulty disk and confirmed this with the manufactures disk checking tool

After adding a new drive the Storage Space came back online and I am now removing the old drive by 'preparing it for removal'. In this process all the data is copied off to the other disks (and in my case to the one i have just added which is obviously empty).

The problem for me was the Bad Blocks were not really being reported in windows or Smart as a problem or an unhealthy disk....so it looked okay but Windows knew it was faulty and could not really be written too. Which then took the Storage Space down.

You do need a lot more than consumer knowledge for Storage Spaces troubleshooting but they do offer a degree of resilience to users data.

hope this helps someone.

Basically look at NTFS logs and disk events in event viewer, work out which drive or drives is the problem and then look to replace them

--All confirmed fixed now

Answer (score 1):

I got the same issue.

First, you need to run `Manage Storage Spaces` as admin. To do that, you need to click on the `Change settings` button.

Once done, you can now click the `Bring online` in your `Storage spaces`

[Check here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZYRdZ.png)

Comment: I do not have the right to post embedded image, sorry.

Comment: Apologies - i had actually done that or tried too. When i try and bring online the machine had a lot of disk activity on the virtual disk but fails to bring it up. Interestingly....my pc is dual boot....and i can mount it successfully on Win 8.1 but on Win 10. Win 10 offers an upgrade option....but if i do that i will no longer be able to recognise it with Win 8. My plan is to low level check each disk and hope i find a bad one to replace.....Not having any luck with Storage Spaces explaining why it is offlining my disk.

Comment: Storage Spaces seems to have a lot of problems ... Tell me when your problem will be fixed. I got often the same error as you and need to bring back online the Storage Spaces.

Comment: I found bad block message so started investigating and found one hdd with a lot of bad blocks after doing a low level scan. I suspect that is the problem. Part of the issue here is that Storage Spaces should give a better alerting and messaging. i am going to swap out the drives tomorrow and see what happens!\