# Storage Spaces Critical Write Error

Tags: windows-10, virtual-machine, raid, hyper-v, storage-spaces

So I have a Windows 10 box with 5 WD Reds in it configured using Storage Spaces.  Last Saturday I performed windows updates on the machine, which brought Windows 10 up to build 1709.  I have three VMs running in Hyper-V which have their VHDX files on the virtual disk created by Storage Spaces, and now these VMs being started all immediately bring the storage space offline due to `Critical Write Errors`.

I already went through with the WD Diagnostic tool and ran extended tests against all of the disks, they are not failing and have no issues.  The rest of the files are perfectly accessible, and the space can be written to.  Just the VMs bring the storage space offline.

I pulled the VHDs off of the virtual disk then booted them up from another disk and they run without issue whatsoever (in fact they run considerably faster, but that could be due to them now being temporarily on a RAID 0 SSD pair)

Running this command yields the following results in powershell:

```
Get-PhysicalDisk 'WDC WD20EFRX-68EUZN0' | Get-StorageReliabilityCounter

DeviceId Temperature ReadErrorsUncorrected Wear PowerOnHours
-------- ----------- --------------------- ---- ------------
2                    0                     0    14637
6                    0                     0    14636
5                    0                     0    14635
4                    0                     0    14635
3                    0                     0    14266
```

I can't seem to find any errors anywhere - all I can chalk this up to is something about the 1709 update killed my ability to run Hyper-V VHDs on a Storage Spaces volume.

Does anyone have any clue how to proceed with this?  I cannot find any information online other than people who actually have failing disks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have resolved this error again with different steps....so posting another Answer.

I was unable to correct the presumed file system errors which prevented me mounting my Virtual Disk in Write mode. Since i was able to bring the disk online using the below command in Read Only mode. I copied all my data off....and wiped the virtual disk and storage pool away and recreate the volume.

Get-VirtualDisk | ?{ $*.ObjectId -Match "{e4cadb43-10be-11e4-826a-005056c00008}" } | Get-Disk | Set-Disk -IsReadOnly $true Get-VirtualDisk | ?{ $*.ObjectId -Match "{e4cadb43-10be-11e4-826a-005056c00008}" } | Get-Disk | Set-Disk -IsOffline $false

All the data is back on the disk, Scan disk is fine and no errors are reported.

I am not impressed with Storage Spaces now... :(

Comment: I am not as well - I think my best solution is to do exactly as you have and migrate to a different storage solution.

Comment: Hi again - so my issues reoccurred and i worked out the pattern from observation of some work flows (installing Star Citizen and copying many pics over from my phone) cause the drive to hang and go into 100% utilization despite having no real drive activity. This goes on until Windows takes offline the Storage Space and it reports Critical Write Error. Apart from those 2 work flows where i can repro at will it works fine. Its defintley a bug, drives are physically fine and now the NTFS volume is fine. I am looking at DrivePool and Flexraid now.

Comment: p.s. many win 10 100% disk util posts about but none of the fixes work for my storage space issue. do you have same pattern?

Comment: I decided to pull off of storage spaces and went to a dedicated LSI hardware raid - no more issues for me

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same issue.... (see below)
[Storage Spaces 'offline due to critical write failures; add drives'](https://superuser.com/questions/1277654/storage-spaces-offline-due-to-critical-write-failures-add-drives)

Basically the Get-StorageReliabilityCounter is useless for identifying issues. I suggest you get a tool from the manufacturer to do an Extended disk test on each drive. For WD i used Data Life Guard and ran 5 copies at once.

This will test for a bad sectors and when identifed an event will be logged in Eventviewer and then crystaldisk info will report data and then finally the Get-StorageReliabilityCounter will have something useful.

Then replace the appropriate disk.

I am now dealing with this issue again....and without jumping the gun i think there may be an issue with WD Reds and Storage spaces....as each time a drive has died i left a bunch of things running on the disk. I think there is a bug.

cheers

Comment: Appreciate the input, but unfortunately as I noted I already in the question I ran extended tests on all the disks from WD and none of the disks came back with any issues.  I have had this setup running for well over a year without any issues using WD Reds on Storage Spaces - the only thing that changed was the update to Windows 10 1709 which leads me to believe that this is the culprit of the issue =(

Comment: If you ever do come up with a solution after having had this issue arise again though please do let me know!

Comment: Hi there - update from my side, i replaced another drive in my Parity storage space which i thought had an issue but still have the issue. I have done an Extended disk test over night - all drives are 100% no bad sectors etc. Yet Storage Spaces will not mount and complains of 'Critical Write Errors', yet there are no Disk or NTFS errors in Event Viewer. I too am on Windows 10 1709. Have you any thoughts as to how to proceed? I really want to be able to get to my data at least in Read Only so i can copy important things off.

Comment: Update - my storage space is now stuck in read only mode and complains of NTFS delayed write and corruption issues if i try and bring online....any idea how i can force it to do a check disk?

Comment: I'm not sure how one would go about putting it into a read only mode @blop001, but sounds like I'm not the only one with this issue since 1709.  Are you storing any Hyper-V virtual disks on your Storage Spaces drives?  I'd like to rule out whether or not Hyper-V is a part of the issue.

Comment: mmm i probably have some VHDs but i dont use Hyper V regularly....VM Workstation all the way here!! :) . And i 100% have not done anything with Hyper V or VHDs in the time frame of this issue. I used this to get into Read Only Mode. I am now copying my data off to an 8 TB hard disk. I then plan to rebuild storage space, full format and another intensive disk test. and then....i am likely to scream Stroage Spaces is rubbish!

Comment: Get-VirtualDisk | ?{ $_.ObjectId -Match "{e4cadb43-10be-11e4-826a-005056c00008}" } | Get-Disk | Set-Disk -IsReadOnly $true                
Get-VirtualDisk | ?{ $_.ObjectId -Match "{e4cadb43-10be-11e4-826a-005056c00008}" } | Get-Disk | Set-Disk -IsOffline  $false

Comment: The problem is that Storage Spaces is such a PoS that in this situation i am in i cannot repair the file structure....i am almost 100% sure there is some sort of NTFS corruption and the disks are fine....but there is no way to repair the volume. rant over.